# Effect on climate of the Earth’s rotation was a week instead of 24 hours

Tags: meteorology, climate, temperature

Cross-posted in [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/175614/75041).

Curious what the affects on daily temperatures and climate would be if the Earth had a slower rotation, say 84 hours of light and 84 hours of darkness. How extreme would the daily highs/lows be? Would there be a significant increase in storms? When would they occur (dawn/dusk)?

Comment: Is a scenario like this too complex to calculate?

Comment: I believe the top-voted answer on the WB is essentially false. The long days & nights are on the poles, where the days and the nights are close to each other. Thus, winds could roughly balance the temperature. But even there is an about 80C difference between the days and the nights. It would not be the case on the equators. I think the likely result would be a >100C temperature on the day, and a <-100C on the night. At least, on the equator. The passate wind is too slow to balance it.

Comment: Answering "what if" settings lead to speclation and is not a discipline of the geosciences, though it may look like when listening to politicians and tabloid media (oops). A projection needs a database, but no data is available. The earth's spheres would have taken different ways right from the beginning, that we can not exclude. How much is world building. Which can be fun :-)

Comment: @a_donda That makes sense. I posted the question on World Building and they suggested I post here. Sounds like there’s some room for handwavium since there are so many variables to consider.